# org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.ModelBuilderService: Provider

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open my Android Studio project get this error
Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.ModelBuilderService: Provider org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.WarModelBuilderImpl could not be instantiated